# How can I find length of kendo dataSource?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I am trying to find length of kendo grid dataSource, but I am always getting 0 in return. How can I get the total length of dataSource? I have added Control service that is dataSource for the grid.

ctrl.js

```
  $scope.alignedProcessesToControlGridOptions.dataSource = ControlRatingGridDataService.getAlignedProcessesToControlGrid($stateParams.controlId);
  var data = $scope.alignedProcessesToControlGridOptions.dataSource.data().length;
  console.log('GRID DATA', data);
```

DataService.js

```
getAlignedProcessesToControlGrid: function(controlKey) {
    var countNew = 0;
    return new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: 'json',
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: function(options) {
                var gridSearchObject = {
                    skip: options.data.skip,
                    take: options.data.take,
                    pageSize: options.data.pageSize,
                    page: options.data.page,
                    sorting: options.data.sort,
                    filter: options.data.filter
                };
                return $http.post(
                    'app/control/rest/allAlignedProcessesToControl/' + controlKey, gridSearchObject).success(
                    function(data) {
                        countNew = data.totalCount;
                        options.success(data.resultDTOList);
                    });
            }

        },
        pageSize: 5,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: 'riskInProcessKey',
                fields: {
                    processName: {
                        editable: false
                    },
                    epcfName: {
                        editable: false
                    },
                    erhName: {
                        editable: false
                    },
                    ctlGeolocationsText: {
                        editable: false
                    },
                    ctlPerformanceRatingText: {
                        editable: false
                    },
                    ctlEffectivenessRatingText: {
                        editable: false
                    }
                }
            },
            total: function() {
                return countNew;
            }
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: what does your `console.log('GRID DATA', data);` return?

Comment: it return 0 all the time

Comment: then you have no data in your datasource

Comment: when my grid is populated with data even then i see data zero in console

Comment: try `var data = $scope.alignedProcessesToControlGridOptions.dataSource.total();`

Comment: nope still see zero in console

Comment: please paste your code from the ControlRatingGridDataService

Comment: i added service to the question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML for the grid looks something like...

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                // your datasource
            },
            dataBound: onDataBound
    });
```

Create a function for the `dataBound` event...

```
function onDataBound(e) {
   console.log(e.sender.dataSource.view().length);
}
```